# Autofac: Check if instance is already resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069002/autofac-resolve-with-and-without-named-parameter

I register an interface. For the initialization a parameter is needed.
A first call will pass this parameter.

On another place i want to resolve this instance of the interface too, but i don't can pass this parameter.
Is it possible to check if this interface was already resolved (in the current scope. I use the ASP.NET WEB API)?
If i resolve it without the parameter, I get an exception.

I need to check if in the current HttpRequest-scope the is already resolved (so I can get it without passing the parameter, because if it is already resolved, the registered creation-delegate will not be called twice)

```
m_builder.Register<IMyClass((c, p) =>
    {
        //...
        return new MyClass;

    }).InstancePerHttpRequest();//.InstancePerApiRequest();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create a class that can track whether the instance is resolved or not:

```
public class Tracker
{
    public bool IsResolved { get; set; }
}
```

(You may wish to pretty this up a bit :))

Register it with the same scope as whatever you want to track:

```
builder.RegisterType<Tracker>()
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Then, in the `OnActivated` event, set the bool:

```
builder.Register((c, p) => {
        return new MyClass();
    })
    .As<IMyClass>()
    .InstancePerHttpRequest()
    .OnActivated(e => {
        e.Context.Resolve<Tracker>().IsResolved = true;
    });
```

You could also set the field during activation (in the first delegate) but using the `OnActivated` event makes it easier to generalise this if you want to.

Finally, to check the field:

```
if (container.Resolve<Tracker>().IsResolved) { ... }
```